# Asterisk blind transfer without disconnect

Tags: asterisk, voip

I have configured blind call transfer and everything works as asterisk document says.

Here is my features.conf

```
[featuremap]
blindxfer = #1
atxfer = *2
```

A and B are already on call. A presses #1 to begin a call transfer to C and gets disconnected.
How do I avoid disconnect so that A can also be in the call.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer SHOULD disconnect original party.

What you want is n-way-calling and usually done via special dialplan and conference room.

There are no native support for n-way in asterisk.

Comment: I checked their guide here: https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-n-way-call-howto/ but sadly macro is deprecated as of now. Gosub also didn't helped at all.

Comment: Sorry, i am not going do your work for you. Rewrite macro to gosub, change to dialplan or use older asterisk version(13.x for sure works with macro).